# Using sklearn pipeline and Feature union

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I cannot seem to debug this problem. It says

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from Transformers import TextTransformer

a = TextTransformer('description', max_features=50)
b = TextTransformer('features', max_features=10)
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('description', a ) # can pass in either a pipeline
    ])
pipeline2 = Pipeline([
    ('features', b) # can pass in either a pipeline
    ])
feat = FeatureUnion([
        ('dpipeline',pipeline),
        ('fpipeline', pipeline2),
    ])
pipe = Pipeline([
        ('featurize', feat),
        ('clf', SVC()),
    ])
pipe.fit(df,df['interest_level'])
pipe.predict(df)
```

Error : `TypeError: expected string or buffer` when i run pipe.fit(df,df['interest_level'])

Why is this so? What i try to do is split up the pipeline and then union them with feature union. The final pipeline will contain all the features and an final estimator.

Comment: What version of python are you using `sklearn` are you using?  `sklearn.__verion__`

Comment: You need to provide more information about the `TextTransformer`. It has to be a proper [estimator](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html). So its a good idea to inherit from `BaseEstimator` and the `TransformerMixin`. Also you don' have to wrap the text transformer in a pipeline. It can go directly in the `FeatureUnion`. Typically you have only one pipeline combining multiple estimators such as feature union etc.

Comment: Please provide full stack trace of error